# Do the Rune Knight's Runes work like spellcasting - or are they different?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, spellcasting, rune-knight

It doesn't say that an invoked rune is controlled by the Rune Knight like a concentration spell or other spell like abilities.

If a rune is invoked, does it stop if the rune knight is knocked unconscious? or can a rune be dispelled by the Rune Knight?

As I read it, it is not a spell affect like an innate spell ability and I don't think that conditions to the Rune Knight affects them nor are they able to drop the effect like a spell.

There isn't anything that says they can un-invoke a spell, the effect just last for 10 rounds or until a save is made. Do the Rune Knight's Runes work like spellcasting - or are they different? How do you read this?

Comment: I adjusted your question to match your inqueries, please let me know if I interpreted you wrong by editing the question yourself.

Answer (score 9):

#### When features require concentration or end when falling unconscious, this is explicitly stated

Let's compare the Rune Knight's Runes to the [Ring of Shooting Stars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-shooting-stars), the [Draconic Sorcerer's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#DraconicBloodline) Draconic Presence feature, and the [Quasit's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/quasit) Invisibility action:

> [...] The spheres last as long as you concentrate (as if concentrating on a spell), up to 1 minute. [...]

> [...] For 1 minute or until you lose your concentration (as if you were casting a concentration spell) [...]

> The quasit magically turns invisible until it attacks or uses Scare, or until its concentration ends (as if concentrating on a spell). [...]

These all explicitly state that they require concentration. But when looking at the Rune Knight, no part of its description states this; therefore, runes do *not* require concentration.

---

As far as falling unconscious is concerned, when effects have specific end conditions, those are stated. We can see this in the [Barbarian's Rage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#Rage-51), the [Druid's Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#WildShape-167), the [Oath of Devotion Paladin's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/paladin#OathofDevotion) Channel Divinity: Sacred Weapon, and the Storm Rune itself:

> [...] Your rage lasts for 1 minute. It ends early if you are knocked unconscious [...]

> [...] You automatically revert if you fall unconscious, drop to 0 hit points, or die. [...]

> [...] If you are no longer holding or carrying this weapon, or if you fall unconscious, this effect ends.

> [...] enter a prophetic state for 1 minute or until you're incapacitated. [...]

These features all *explicitly* end when unconscious (and in the case of the Storm Rune, incapacitating alone is enough). Since all the other runes lack any similar text, we can conclude that they do *not* end when falling unconscious.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the abilities technically aren't those of the Rune Knight themselves, but of the item that the runes are carved into, and function like any other activated magic item.

Comment: @nick Except when they don't, like in my last example. I'm not sure what that would really add since magic items can similarly have their own rules aplenty

Comment: Yeah I read it the same as everyone is describing. I felt that we played with the rune not ending when I fell unconscious. The area where I disagreed with was when I failed a wisdom save and was suggested to take the shackles off. I was told I dispelled them. I don't think you can do that. I felt flame shackles are like a Bear trap for a hunter. You could try to open the trap with a strength save, but you can't just cancel the trap after it was sprung.